# Is it possible to show some php content inside an html image?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, iframe

Is it possible to display some php content within an HTML image (say display on the screen of an iPhone where iPhone being an image)

Comment: Yes it is very much possible. There are loads of php scripts that do what `www.danasoft.com` does. It used to be fun awhile ago on forums.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, if you just want to overlay text on an image, why create an image at all.
you can use css background image(iphone in this case) for a div and the insert your phpp content as a child of that div. Using proper css styling and positioning, you will get your desired look. Its simple and less server consuming than going the image creation way.

Answer (score 2):

You could generate your own image on the server using the [GD library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) to overlay your content onto the image and then send that to the client.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to achieve the same effect, without requiring any server processing; however, it must be an image, you might want to check out the image processing library that allows you to manipulate images using PHP http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php.